# Ansible 2.1.2 playbook pass SSH password and sudo password as command line args

Tags: ansible

I've looked around but couldn't find a proper solution, I want to run playbook for multiple users on multiple hosts and my roles use the user specific info such as name, email, id ... Now instead of running the playbook for each user I wrote a python script that invokes the ansible

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts --ask-become-pass --ask-pass ./playbooks/myplaybook.yml
```

But for the above command to work I want to pass SSH password and SUDO password as arguments to the command. I checked ansible-playbook documentation but was unable to find it. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to run playbook multiple times under different accounts? I believe there is a better approach to handle different uses inside playbook and run it under superuser.

Comment: The only other way was to write playbooks for each user and nest them

Answer (score 17):

You can specify the following parameters from the command line:

```
… -e "ansible_user=username ansible_ssh_pass=xxx ansible_sudo_pass=xxx" …
```